# Learning mapreduce, How is a SQL command translated in map reduce data flow. Word count example is not satisfying my understanding.

Tags: scala, hadoop, nosql, mapreduce, hive

Online, I see so many examples of the canonical word count map reduce walk through. I understand mapper input of k,v => to reduce input of k,list(v). Some magic goes on by map reduce. i dont quite understand how to apply mapreduce to a more practical example. for example: let's say I have a file containing salaries of all employees in the US with some other details such as state and city etc... How would mapreduce work to provide an output report containing the following columns aggregated? State, city, avg(salaries)

In SQL I can get this with a query like this:

```
Select state, city, avg(salaries) 
From employee_tbl
Group by state, city
```

How will map reduce work to give me the abover result set. I have used hive but I don't know how that SQL gets translated to map and reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly translate a SQL query to a set of Map/Reduce jobs, you should definitely take a look at [YSmart](http://ysmart.cse.ohio-state.edu/). It is just a SQL to Map/Reduce built on top of Hadoop. Also some studies have shown it might be faster than Hive, although I can't back this claim as I haven't tested it myself.

As taken from their docs, YSmart provides:

- **High Performance**: The MapReduce programs generated by YSmart are optimized. YSmart can automatically detect and utilize intra-query correlations when translating a query. This correlation-aware ability significantly reduces redundant computation, unnecessary disk IO operations and network overhead. See the Performance page to learn the performance benefits of YSmart.
- **High Extensibility**: YSmart is easy to modify and extend. It is designed with the goal of extensibility. The major part of YSmart is implemented in Python which makes the codes much easier to understand. Due to its modularity and script nature, users can easily modify the current functionalities or add new functionalities to YSmart.
- **High Flexibility**: YSmart can run in two different modes: translation-mode and execution-mode. In the translation-mode, YSmart only translates the query into Java codes while in the execution-mode YSmart will also compile and execute the generated codes. Because of this flexibility, users can easily read, modify and customize the generated codes.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to covert your SQL query in a map-reduce job would be using HIVE over Hadooop.

But in case you dont want that,a simple rule of thumb that you can apply in most of the examples while emulating an SQL query to a map-reduce Job is-

> Key-Out in Map function are the columns in your group by clause.

In your example let state-city be a key,which you will output in your Map function(use some seperator between them).

> Value-out in your Map function is the column on which you want to run aggregation function.

In your example it would be individual salary(if there are more than 1 columns that you want to aggregate can separate thew by the same separator).

> Key-in in Reduce will be the same as key-out of Map function

.

> Value-out in reduce function will be the value after running aggregation function over value-out of all rows which have the same key

So in this case you will just sum up all the value-in(salary) and value-out will be the sum of salaries in a unique 'state-city' pair.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: if I want to aggregate over a few columns, I have to make sure those columns to aggregate over form the concatenated key, and the value is the number to aggregate over. Right?

Comment: yes.now if you want than 1 number to aggregate over you can concatenate those in the value Out of mapper and aggregate by breaking  them again in reducer